# Unclickable footerView while ListView is scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView, with a footer attached to it, which is Button. This Button works fine when there is no Scrolling involved. 
When the listView is scrolling, it becomes unclickable, like the other items in the ListView. Since it takes some time after the View have reached bottom, and the View actually stops "Scrolling", the footer(Button) is unclickable for a sec or 2. Is it possible to make an item, in this case a ListView footer, clickable while the ListView is scrolling? Or another clever solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to make the button.setClickable(true). it should be clickable during the scrolling

Comment: Its inside a LinearLayout. Dont know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: No, It shouldn't matter. Did you try cleaning the project then running the app?

Comment: Yeah, tried it. Didnt work. Maybe im doing something else wrong.. Hmm. Just setting it clickable right after intitilizing it. Tried doing it in xml too

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like another one of a very long list of problems with ListView stealing touch events from its child views.  The solution is to use RecyclerView instead.  ListView is essentially deprecated and RecyclerView is the replacement.